# generate diagrams from hibernate models

Tags: java, hibernate

I have the codebase and SQL creation script of a legacy Spring+Hibernate app, to be retired and migrated. I have limited knowledge of Java (and legacy frameworks), so generating a model diagram may be helpful to understand the old data (and logic).

The SQL script has no foreign keys, but noticed XMLs annotated with models with fields and their relationships for Hibernate.

What's the easiest way to generate model diagrams from these Hibernate XMLs? [DjangoGraphviz](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DjangoGraphviz) could be installed to generate models diagrams in a moment. Is there a similar method/tool with Hibernate?

Comment: sorry, but i think calling Spring an Hibernate legacy frameworks is a bit bold ! using xml to map entities is allowedly a bit 'oldschool'

Answer (score 5):

With Hibernate you have Java references between the entities, so any tool visualizing class dependencies might help.

I'm the author of it so I obviously recommend [Degraph](http://schauder.github.io/degraph/), but there are many out there. Just google java dependency visualization.

Comment: Could you tell how to do it with Hibernate? Going through the docs right now

Comment: @Jens Schauder nice tool ! when i saw your answer i remembered a JUG talk about it.

Comment: Its throwing `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` even with `-Xmx2500m`. How to mitigate?

Comment: Make sure you only analyze your code (not the complete JDK and your dependencies) If that doesn't help, please create an issue at github or a question here at stackoverflow. If u chose the later let me know via a comment here.

Comment: Thx @AndréR. I like it too :->

Comment: I have asked a specific question on degraph https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31294201/how-to-use-degraph-to-graph-only-models

Answer (score 1):

i don't now of any tools to do that in a straight forward way.

- you could of course do it on your own. for example use xslt to transform your xml-mapping files to the graphml (xml) format and use a tool like 'yed' (https://www.yworks.com/en/products/yfiles/yed/) to layout and draw a nice diagram.
- as a tool to understand legacy code [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.org/) has served me well because it allows you to browse the package structure, the source, the javadoc and generated UML Diagrams at the same time.
- if you need to understand the structures at a database level ... i found 
  [Schemacrawler](http://schemacrawler.sourceforge.net/) quite helpful.