# How to use Degraph to graph only models

Tags: java, degraph

I want to generate relationship graph among model classes using degraph.

Here is a representative example model, a POJO TaskEntryImpl that relates to Task:

```
package com.packag.tm.model.pojo;
public class TaskEntryImpl implements TaskEntry,Serializable {

    private Integer id;
    private Task task;

    public Task getTask() {
        return this.task;
    }
    public void setTask(Task v) {
        this.task = v;
    }
```

Packages containing models have `model.pojo` as part of the package name:

```
com.somepackage.events.model.pojo.DurationImpl
au.com.anotherpackage.ecrm.model.pojo.PayphoneImpl
```

How do I get a graph of models that meet the abovementioned characteristics?

---

For the curious: I wish I could have an Entity-Relation diagram instead.

These model classes are wired by Hibernate ORM. The original developers maintained SQL independent of the codebase and have never used foreign keys. So this rules out getting an entity-relation diagram from the database schema.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file `pojo.config` with the following content

```
output = pojo.graphml
classpath = yourlib.jar
include = **.model.pojo.**
```

For getting started I'd put the file straight in the `bin` directory of Degraph.

The `classpath` value must point to the byte code you want to analyze, so either a jar-file or the directory, which contains all the class-files.

Now run (again from the bin directory):

```
degraph -f pojo.config
```

Degraph should print out the number of classes found and create a file `pojo.graphml` in the current directory (i.e. bin). You can open that with [yed](http://www.yworks.com/en/products/yfiles/yed/).

See the documentation of [Degraph for how to create a useful layout with yed](http://schauder.github.io/degraph/documentation.html#working-with-yed).

Note that Degraph will create boxes for the packages and put the boxes for classes into these package boxes. You can open the package boxes and then delete the package boxes, if you don't like them.